# How to best implement a blocking/waiting actor?

Tags: asynchronous, redis, akka, actor, nonblocking

I'm fairly new to Akka and writing concurrent applications and I'm wondering what's a good way to implement an actor that would wait for a redis list and once an item becomes available it will process it, or send it to a different actor to process?

Would using the blocking function BRPOPLPUSH be better, or would a scheduler that will ask the actor to poll redis every second be a better way?

Also, on a normal system, how many of these actors can I spawn concurrently without consuming all the resource the system has to offer? How does one decide how many of each Actor type should an actor system be able to handle on the system its running on?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you should never block inside `receive`. Each actor should rely only on CPU and never wait, sleep or block on I/O. When these conditions are met you can create even millions of actors working concurrently. Each actor is suppose to have 600-650 bytes memory footprint (see: [*Concurrency, Scalability & Fault-tolerance 2.0 with Akka Actors & STM*](http://www.slideshare.net/jugmilano/akka-110124155752phpapp02)).

Back to your main question. Unfortunately there is no [official Redis client](http://redis.io/clients) "compatible" with Akka philosophy, that is, completely asynchronous. What you need is a client that instead of blocking will return you a `Future` object of some sort and allow you to register callback when results are available. There are such clients e.g. for Perl and node.js.

However I found [fyrie-redis](https://github.com/derekjw/fyrie-redis) independent project which you might find useful. If you are bound to synchronous client, the best you can do is either:

- poll Redis periodically without blocking and inform some actor by sending a message to with a Redis reply or
- block inside an actor and [understand the consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458782)

## See also

- [Redis client library recommendations for use from Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878367)

Answer (score 0):

`BRPOPLPUSH` with block for long time (up to the timeout you specify), so I would favour a `Scheduler` instead which still blocks, but for a shorter amount of time every second or so.

Whichever way you go, because you are blocking, you should read [this section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management) of the Akka docs which describes methods for working with blocking libraries.

Do you you have control over the code that is inserting the item into redis? If so you could get that code to send your akka code a message (maybe over ActiveMQ using the akka camel support) to notify it when the item has been inserted into redis. This will be a more event driven way of working and prevent you from having to poll, or block for super long periods of time.